# Python Range() for positive and negative numbers

Tags: python-2.7, range, negative-number

Okay, so I'm trying to write a simple program that gives me both the positive
and negative range of the number given by the user.

For example, if the user gives number 3 then the program should prints out
-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3

I've tried thinking but just can't think how to get the negative range outputs.
But the code I got below only gives me the positive range outputs, so I was
thinking may I need to do to make it gives me both the positive and negative
outputs.

```
 s = int(input("Enter a number "))
 for i in range(s+1):
     print i+1
```

Comment: have you looked at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)?

Comment: Yea, I've looked at it before. But I'm confused at some parts and can't really understand it. Don't really understand the stop and step..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`Range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) can take two parameters: `range(start, end)`, where start is inclusive, and end is exclusive. So the range you want for 3 is: `range(-3, 4)`. To make it general:

```
s = int(input("Enter a number "))
for i in range(-s, s+1):
    print i
```